# Grails3 integration-test fails with an error

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0, integration-testing

I am getting following error with Integration test cases in grails 3.0.2. Even with just one simple canary integration test.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyMarkupConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Groovy configuration, or set spring.groovy.template.check-template-location=false)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Groovy configuration, or set spring.groovy.template.check-template-location=false)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyMarkupConfiguration.checkTemplateLocationExists(GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 42 more
```

I am using Grails 3.0.2 with JDK 1.7, Groovy2.4.3 and Gradle 2.3.

Comment: Have you tried setting the spring.groovy.template.check-template-location to false?

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9038). I tried the suggested workaround, but it didn't work for me, so I reverted back to 3.0.1.

Comment: @Ivojnovic yes it was there in application.yml.

Comment: @Ken Thanks! for the link. After replacing application.yml with application.groovy everything working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug with grails 3.0.2 as mentioned over [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9038). It will be fixed in grails 3.0.3 release. Till then, replace your applcation.yml with application.groovy like below.

```
grails {
    profile = 'web'
    codegen {
        defaultPackage = 'org.grails.plugins'
    }
}

info {
    app {
        name = '@info.app.name@'
        version = '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion = '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
    }
}

spring {
    groovy {
        template['check-template-location'] = false
    }
}

hibernate {
    naming_strategy = 'org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy'
    cache {
        queries = false
    }
}

grails {
    mime {
        disable {
            accept {
                header {
                    userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
                }
            }
        }

        types {
            all = '*/*'
            atom = 'application/atom+xml'
            css = 'text/css'
            csv = 'text/csv'
            form = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            html = ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml']
            js = 'text/javascript'
            json = ['application/json', 'text/json']
            multipartForm = 'multipart/form-data'
            rss = 'application/rss+xml'
            text = 'text/plain'
            hal = ['application/hal+json', 'application/hal+xml']
            xml = ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
        }
    }
    urlmapping {
        cache {
            maxsize = 1000
        }
    }
    controllers {
        defaultScope = 'singleton'
    }
    converters {
        encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
    views {
        'default' { codec = 'html' }//THIS WAS THE SOURCE OF ERROR
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml'
            codecs {
                expression = 'html'
                scriptlets = 'html'
                taglib = 'none'
                staticparts = 'none'
            }
        }
    }
}

dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
}


// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
                // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057329/convert-configuration-file-application-yml-to-application-groovy-in-grails-3-x)!